# Unexpected(?) dependency on Microsoft Database Engine Runtime 2010

Tags: entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

I am using EntityFrameworkCore with the Jet-Provider to connect to an mdb-file.
I am using the OleDB drivers with following connection string

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin; Data Source={0};Mode=Share Deny None;Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1};`

Everything works as I expected it, but we discovered that we get an exception when we try to run the application without an installation of MS Access or the Access Database Engine 2010 runtime. However in our previous application we did not have this dependency. There we used the ADO-Components and it worked seemingly 'out of the box'.

The exception:

> Cannot create database
> "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\xxxx\db.mdb" using DAO. --->
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Die COM-Klassenfactory
> für die Komponente mit CLSID {CD7791B9-43FD-42C5-AE42-8DD2811F0419}
> konnte aufgrund des folgenden Fehlers nicht abgerufen werden: 80040154
> Klasse nicht registriert (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80040154
> (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Is there a way to achieve this with the ef core provider? If not, why?